# JQuery Mobile Disable/Enable Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have noticed that disabling and enabling in jQuery Mobile is a little more involved then with jQuery. Looking through I have noticed that we need to call the control type, and disable it:

`$('[type="submit"]').button('enable');`

The problem is that this will not work for me. I have multiple controls of many different types, and I not all of them have supported jQuery Mobile methods (`select-one`, for example does not appear to not have any method).

I am currently trying to do the following:

```
function DisableControlMobile(control, disabled) {
    if(control){
        var type = control.type;
        //Ugly, but we need to get the id string so we can build the jQuery call, as the methods used will throw errors if we do not do this
        var id = control.id;
        console.log(type + " " + id + " " + disabled);
        if (disabled) {
            $('#' + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#' + id).addClass('ui-disabled'); 
            $('#' + id).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        } else {
            $('#' + id).removeClass('ui-disabled');
            $('#' + id).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('#' + id).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
}
```

All of my items are asp items. Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ArrivalTimeTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="time_textbox" data-clear-btn="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

It appears that the add and remove class calls do not do anything, as there are a ton of divs that are used as wrappers, and they all contain the disabled classes as well.

Comment: For text input use `.textinput("disable")`.

Comment: That works in some cases, but the problem is that not all items are of type textinput (some are buttons, or selects).

Comment: For `button` and `a` add class `ui-state-disabled`. For select `.selectmenu("disable")`. For input type button, submit, rest `.button("disable")`.

Comment: Well that could cover everything I am seeing. Ill try that now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I ended up using a mixture of both your comment and my current solution to get it to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a perfect solution, but if the code will not know what sort of control it will enable/disable, this seems to be the best solution (at least that I could come up with).

```
    if (disabled) {
        $('#' + id).parent().addClass('ui-disabled');
        $('#' + id).parent().addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('#' + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#' + id).addClass('ui-disabled'); 
        $('#' + id).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    } else {
        $('#' + id).parent().removeClass('ui-disabled');
        $('#' + id).parent().removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('#' + id).removeClass('ui-disabled');
        $('#' + id).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('#' + id).attr('disabled', "");
    }
```